# Tratando arquivo XML com PHP

Tags: php, xml

Eu tenho o seguinte XML:

```
<offer categoryId="3588" id="154394195459775522">
    <offerName>
        CAMISETA DROP DEAD PRODUCTION – MASCULINA VERDE ESCURO
    </offerName>
    <links>
        <link url="http://links.lomadee.com/ls/d25zZjsyRHd2U1I3MzsyODY4NjE3OTswOzU3OTg7MDs1NzE0O0JSOzM7aHR0cCUzQSUyRiUyRnd3dy5jZW50YXVyby5jb20uYnIlMkZwcm9tb2NhbyUzRm5leHRVcmwlM0R0LXNoaXJ0LWRyb3AtZGVhZC1wcm9kdWN0aW9uLTcwMjE0MDE4LTgxODE2OC5odG1sJTI2dHlwZSUzRHBkcCUyNmlkJTNEODE4MTY4JTI2dXRtX3NvdXJjZSUzRExvbWFkZWUlMjZ1dG1fbWVkaXVtJTNEeG1sJTI2dXRtX2NhbXBhaWduJTNETG9tYWRlZS1Ta2F0ZS1DYW1pc2V0YS0tODE4MTY4LTg2JTI2b3JpZ2VtJTNETG9tYWRlZTswOzA-.html" type="offer"/>
    </links>
    <thumbnail url="http://images.centauro.com.br/250x250/81816886.jpg"/>
    <price>
        <currency abbreviation="BRL"/>
        <value>49.9</value>
        <parcel>
            <value>24.95</value>
            <number>2</number>
            <interest>0.0</interest>
        </parcel>
    </price>
    <seller id="84" isTrustedStore="false" pagamentoDigital="false" advertiserId="5714" oneClickBuy="false" oneClickBuyValue="0" cpcDifferentiated="false">
        <sellerName>Centauro</sellerName>
        <thumbnail url="https://wwws.lomadee.com/programas/BR/5714/logo_185x140.png"/>
        <links>
            <link url="http://www.centauro.com.br" type="seller"/>
        </links>
    </seller>
    <startOffer>1969-12-31T21:00:00-03:00</startOffer>
    <endOffer>8994-08-17T04:12:55.807-03:00</endOffer>
    <category id="3588" isFinal="true">
        <thumbnail url="http://imagem.buscape.com.br/bp5/categorias/3588.jpg"/>
        <name>Shorts Esportivo</name>
    </category>
</offer>
```

Chamei o xml, via php da seguinte maneira:

```
 <?php 
$xml = simplexml_load_file('arquivo.xml');  
foreach ($xml as $details){
    echo "<href='" . $details->links ."'>" . $details->offerName . "</a><br >";
    echo $details->thumbnail . '<br >';
    echo "R$" . $details->price->value . '<br >';
    echo $details->price->parcel->value->number . '<br >';
    echo $details->seller->sellerName . '<br >';

    echo '<br >';
    }
?>
```

O problema é que está mostrando apenas o título, sem o link. Mostra o valor, sem o parcelamento. Não mostra o thumbnail.

Adicionando ----->

Conforme o código informado acima, ele trás um resultado em branco sempre na primeira linha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bem, de acordo com seu XML, você está trabalhando com uma oferta, então quando você utiliza o foreach para percorrer o XML, ele passará por todos os nós filhos da tag principal . Sendo assim quando você faz a chamada, por exemplo, “$details->offerName”, lhe retornará um vazio.

Aconselho a fazer a leitura e chamar os elementos individualmente desta forma:

```
<?php 
    $details = simplexml_load_file('arquivo.xml');  

    echo "<a href='" . $details->links[0]->link["url"] ."'>" . $details->offerName . "</a><br >";
    echo $details->thumbnail["url"] . '<br >';
    echo "R$" . $details->price->value . '<br >';
    echo $details->price->parcel->value->number . '<br >';
    echo $details->seller->sellerName . '<br >';
    echo '<br >';
?>
```

Comment: tentei assim, e nenhum dado apareceu na tela.

Comment: Errado, ele está iterando `offer. Para acessar dessa forma seria algo como `$details->offer->blablabla`

Comment: Não está, ele está iterando os nós filhos do offer verifique no manual do PHP [link](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.simplexml-load-file.php) os exemplos.

Comment: Acho que é por ai @casscarraro , problema é que nem todos dados estão aparecendo, já testei de várias maneiras e nada.

Comment: Realmente, está iterando os filhos. executei o código aqui. Falha minha.

Comment: Bem, @GustavoCave para pegar os elementos você pode utilizar como no exemplo que eu citei acima, utilize o $details->"nome do nó". Caso você queira buscar todos os dados você pode utilizar o foreach, no entanto você deve cuidar com os elementos que possuem filhos, como no caso dos “links”, que você terá que utilizar outro foreach para percorrer ou buscar um elemento fixo como eu dei o exemplo do “$details->links[0]”.

Comment: @casscarraro criei 1 variável $a = links[0]->link["url"] e chamei a variável no echo dentro do href. Ainda não obtive sucesso.

Comment: Você deve atribuir o valor da $details->links[0]->link["url"], ou seja, $a = $details->links[0]->link["url"].

Comment: Infeslimente sem sucesso, vou tentar outras maneiras, qualquer outra ajuda é bem-vinda, obrigado por tudo até o momento. casscarraro e gmsantos!

Comment: Dentro do xml na tag <link> tem uma chamada do tipo type=offer, isso não está influenciando será?

Comment: Eu fiz um echo $details->links[0]->link["url"] . <br>;  e mostrou o link, mas quando coloco ele dentro do href, não funciona

Comment: Ele funcinou, mas sem usar variável. Ficou assim: echo "<a href='" . $details->links[0]->link["url"] ."'>" . $details->offerName . "</a><br >";

Answer (score 1):

Tenha atenção ao utilizar o XML. Todos seus erros são relacionados ao tentar usar elementos de forma errada, sem seguir a estrutura do seu documento.

Note também que alguns dados são atributos dos elementos. Você pode acessar esses atributos através de um array do elemento.

Conforme observado também na resposta do @casscarraro, seu foreach está iterando os filhos de `offer`. Como seu arquivo só tem uma oferta, o `foreach` é desnecessário.

---

1- Para exibir o thumbnail, você deve colocar o conteúdo dentro da tag `img` e acessar o atributo url.

```
echo '<img src="' . $details->thumbnail["url"] . '">';
```

2 - `$details->links` é um grupo de links, o correto é associar ao elemento correto

```
echo "<href='" . $details->links->link->["url"] ."'>"
```

3 - Novamente, você especificou o caminho errado no seu xml para exibir a parcela.

```
echo $details->price->parcel->number . '<br >';
```

4 - O link não está aparecendo pois a tag do link está incorreta, faltou o `a`

```
echo "<a href='{$link_url}'> {$xml->offerName} </a><br >";
```

No final o código corrigido fica assim:

```
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_file('arquivo.xml');

$link_url = $xml->links->link["url"];
$imagem_url = $xml->thumbnail["url"];

echo "<a href='{$link_url}'> {$xml->offerName} </a><br >";
echo "<img src='{$imagem_url}'><br >";
echo "R$ {$xml->price->value} <br >";
echo "{$xml->price->parcel->number}x de {$xml->price->parcel->value} <br >";
echo "{$xml->seller->sellerName} <br >";

echo "<br >";

?>
```

Comment: Apenas o parcelamento funcionou. O link e o thumbnail ainda não.

Comment: Sabe alguma solução?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function attributes() on a non-object...

Comment: Agora sim. Corrigido

Comment: Sem sucesso, não aparece nada da tela. Tentei igual o meu código original, acrescentando as variáveis $link_url e $imagem_url e chamando elas no echo e não obtive sucesso tbm, mas os dados aparecem.